# Executing external program via system() does not run properly

Tags: c++, linux, system

I try to call a program (ncbi blast, for those who need to know) from my code, via calling the command in a system() call.

If I execute the string directly in the shell, it works as intended, but if I try the same string via system(), the program returns much faster, without the intended results. The output file is created, but the file size is 0. The returned error code is also 0. I even tried appending "> output.log 2> error.log" but these files are not created.

I guess it has something to do with environment variables or the path...

The output file name is given via -o command line parameter, not output redirection.

I read something about the popen command being possibly better suited for my use-case, but I can not find it, which library is that from?

Comment: Tried specifying the full path to the program in the system() call?

Comment: How do you launch the parent app?

Comment: @moonshadow yes, the full path is specified for the system() call

Comment: @Bernard in the same shell where I tried the call, directly. ".\myProgram"

Comment: The redirection operators only work in the shell environment, and won't affect the behaviour of the app via system. Are you sure the files are not being created else where?

Comment: Did you check to see what system call returns to you?

Comment: @Bernard the output file I want is not created with redirection, rather with the -o parameter. The file is created, but it is empty. I guess the program misses the ~/.ncbirc config file and can not find it. This file specifies the location of the database to blast against.

Comment: @navigator as I wrote somewhere in the essay up there, the return value is 0. So no error there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most usual cause of such problems is incorrect environment variable setting in ones `~/.bashrc`.

You should be able to see what `ncbi` is unhappy about by executing

```
$SHELL -c '<exact string you pass to system()>'
```

Another common way to debug this is with `strace`. Execute:

```
strace -fo /tmp/strace.out ./myProgram
```

and look in `/tmp/strace.out` for clues.

Answer (score 1):

Is there any reason that you do not want to `fork` and `exec`? This is a common idiom for executing one process from another.

Answer (score 0):

popen is in the standard C library
[See the man page](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/popen/)

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, swapping system() with similar popen() calls did not produce the desired results. Using popen(), I tried to look at the possible error messages or any output, without success.

Comment: Out of interest is there a reason you can't call the program directly ?  I googled the program you mentioned, can't say it's my field!

Comment: If system() does not work then using popen() is not going to solve the problem. If it did work with system() then swapping to popen() would probably be preferable.

Comment: @Chris: I'm writing a wrapper program which performs parameter sweeps ans stuff like that, calls blast multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

Some quick questions:

- How do you execute in in the shell?
- How do you execute in the system command?
- What is the value returned by system?

Exact copy and paste from you terminal is preferable then an English description.